# How is energy distributed over the normal modes?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, waves, normal-modes

Consider a linear chain of $N$ point masses $m$ connected by linear springs $k$ and fixed at the two ends by rigid walls separated by a distance $L=N\times l$.

If I take the point mass at the center $m_{i}=m_{\frac{N}{2}}$ and pull it by small distance $\delta x$ to the right, and then release, then

(1) How is energy distributed over the normal modes ?

(2) Does this distribution change if energy transfer between modes is allowed via non-linear instead of linear springs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1): if you solve the linear eigenvalue system of normal modes, you can construct the most general solution as $f \propto \sum_j c_j o_j(t) d_j(x)$ where $o_j(t)$ is the time dependence of mode $j$ and $d_j(x)$ is the spatial dependence. Then at $t=0$ you just do the Fourier transform and find the coefficients $c_j$ that depends on the initial condition distribution.
Then, the energy distribution is basically $|c_j|^2$ (normalized such that the sum equals the initial energy content).

(2): if you have non-linear terms in the equation of motion, simply the $c_j$ will be functions of time as well $c_j(t)$, and there will be a "statistical" steady-state, time-averaged, for which the average $c_j$ distribution could be different than the linear one for sure (but what exactly you end up with, depends on the type and strength of non-linear couplings).

Comment: Yes this would simple standard methodology. But I am looking in literature and here for established qualitative knowledge about the expected behaviour before formalising and calculating the problem. For example what sort of dependence should be expected of $k$ and $m$ ?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: yes, I just got how to use it. will do from next one! Btw thanks a lot for having edited mine!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The community bot seems to have closed my question because of bad formatting in this answer, great..

Comment: @YoussefMabrouk:  What seems to have happened is that some users thought your question was asking for "homework help" and voted to close it;  it had nothing to do with this answer.  I've voted to re-open your question, and hopefully it will be reopened soon.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Thank you.